# Required solution for Thread Constructor and solution to start thread for my code

Tags: c#, multithreading, constructor

I am trying to assign value to my variable in default constructor and Thread Construction. However, I am unable to identify how to solve this issue.

I have created a for loop through which I am assigning my value as well as to Start the Thread.

1. How can I solve ThreadStart(InitializeServer(I))?

   -> Error: Method name expected
2. What is the other way around for this. ServerInitialization.Start();

   -> If I use workerThread.Start() will all individual thread would start? Example Such as Server 1, Server 2?

ServerInitialization.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace MyApplication
{
    public  class ServerInitialization
    {
        public int serverID;
        static private int ServersInStore = MainApplication.numofServers;

        public ServerInitialization(int serverNum)
        {
            this.serverID = serverNum;
        }
        
        public static void InitializeServer(int sId)
        {
            ServerInitialization _id = new ServerInitialization(sId);
            _id.serverID = sId;
        }
        public static void AssignServer(int totalServers)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<totalServers; ++i)
            {
                Thread workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(InitializeServer(i)));
                ServerInitialization.Start();
            }
            
        }
    }
```

MainApplication.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace MyApplication
{
    public class MainApplication
    {
        public static int numofServers = 0;
           
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How servers required?");
            numofServers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            
            ServerInitialization.AssignServer(numofServers);
        }
    }
}
```

Recreating my C# issue in Java project.

GenerateServer.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GenerateServer {

       protected static int NumOfServers=4;

       public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           
           Server.InitializeServer();
           
           
    }

}
```

Server.java

```
public class Server implements Runnable{
    private int serverID;
       //private Customer atCounter;
       static private int ServersInStor=GenerateServer.NumOfServers;
      
       public Server(int serverID)
       {
           this.serverID=serverID;
       }  
      
       public static void InitializeServer()
       {
          for (int i=0; i<GenerateServer.NumOfServers; ++i)
          {
              Thread Server = new Thread(new Server(i));           
              Server.start();                  
          }
       }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `ServerInitialization.Start();` do, and you don't seem to be doing anything with `workerThread`?

Comment: @Charlieface It simply starts the Thread with an ID, I am assigning with I. So If I want my numofServers to be 4. It creates 4 threads wth the assigned serverID to it.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you save the new `workerThread` so I don't see how it could be started. It seems you may have removed essential parts of your code. Please show all relevant code

Comment: @Charlieface I don't know how should I use it that's why I asked Question 2!!! I tried to recreate the same issue but with a different Programming Language - "Java". And I was able to do it as expected. However, I am unable to succeed in C#. Also, I have included all relevant code for both C# and Java. Please see my java code and help me to solve issue in C#. Thanks.

Comment: So to answer your main question: I expect you need `Thread workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => InitializeServer(i)));` and then the following line should be `workerThread.Start();`

Comment: if you write  `InitializeServer(i)` then it will give you as an error  *Method name expected*

Comment: You didn't look at what I wrote. It's a lambda `() => InitializeServer(i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can just use an anonymous lambda function

```cs
Thread workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => InitializeServer(i)));
```

Or in short:

```cs
Thread workerThread = new Thread(() => InitializeServer(i));
```